# How did Seebeck make the potential measurements?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, history

I'm studying electromagnetism and I start wandering how did Ohm make its potential measurements (I mean for the formulation of its law, that is nowadays used for potentials measurements in a circuit).
I surfed and it turns out he used the Seebeck effect with a thermocouple to make measurements.

So now my question is: how did Seebeck make its potential measurements?( And so how we can measure the potentials in a circuit in a non Ohm law dependent way?)

Comment: According to this document in French, it is Ohm who made the measurements on the Seebeck effect (fig 5) with the equation X=ab+x and considers that this new formula also applies to the case of the voltaic battery. 
http://www.ampere.cnrs.fr/parcourspedagogique/zoom/courant/ohm/index.php

Comment: Is there an English version?

Comment: There is this link https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/science-and-technology/physics-biographies/georg-simon-ohm